# Locking of the jaw during workout related stress

Tags: muscle, exercise-technique

The sympathetic nervous system (SNS) is involved in energy expenditure as it drives the body to respond to stress. So when one is lifting weight or doing a pullup or pushup and is about to finish the repetition specially during last two the jaw bone locks,  the parasympathetic nervous system (PSNS), acts as the calming, energy-conserving and healing branch of the ANS. Balancing out this locking of the jaw after the session is over. However when the balance between the two is lost, the jaw stays locks up for more then 30 secs after the stress is released. Does anybody have idea of the direct this response to other area so the jaw is released after at the end of the repetition. ? Or how to restore the balance ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a chat with your dentist they will be able to guide you. My jaw used to lock when I ran and we traced it back to eating apples before running! Good to eat them but the extra stress on the jaw before exercise was the cause. To relax my jaw I massaged the side of my jaw, gently, on both sides.

But the best thing is your dentist, they are specialists and everyone is different. The teeth/jaw symptoms are sometimes misleading.